# Proper Way to display images from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

From what I´ve read from the official [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) and after watching [this firecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lzEgwiSs-M) my understanding is that in order to display images on a client there are two approaches:

The first is server based,using functions and writing the `SignedUrls` to the database.

The second is client based using `StorageReference` and pointing to the desired path in storage.

I have decided to follow the second approach due to the fact that the Firebase client SDK gives you the ability to directly query a storage photo for additional useful information about the photo (creation date,metadata etc) without the need of creating additional entries in the database 
(like in the `SignedUrl` case by using `functions.storage.ObjectMetadata`).

My questions are:

1) can the bucket name or the full internal photo path be used in the client code without any security risks?

The path form may be:
`gs://myapp.appspot.com/bucket_folder/username/photoname.PNG`               (non-default bucket)

2) Are there any drawbacks by using the client SDK method over the server-produced `SignedUrls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to access items in Cloud Storage through the Firebase SDK:

1. By using the Firebase SDK methods to access the data.
2. By using the download URL.

When you use the download URL, the user doesn't have to be signed in. But the user can only ever read the file and (as you discovered) will only have access to the raw payload of the file, not the metadata.

When you use the other methods of the Firebase SDK, your access is controlled by the security rules. So your user may have to sign in.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Frank, in case the storage location or bucket name is hard coded in the client app are there any additional security concerns if it is exposed?

Comment: The bucket name is just an identifier that allows the code to find the data. It's not more a security concern than exposing your say user id (mine is 209103 here on Stack Overflow, yours is 6453904) - knowing these does not allow abuse.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying!